# Get post thumbnail with Wordpress REST API

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, post

I use this code to get posts via Wordpress REST API, this code work very and get posts well but i dont know how i can get post thumbnail wit this. I added ?_embed to end of URL in wp_remote_get function and thumbnail address are in output but i don't no how i can fetch and display image url in php.

```
<?php

function get_posts_via_rest() {

    // Initialize variable.
    $allposts = '';
    
    // Enter the name of your blog here followed by /wp-json/wp/v2/posts and add filters like this one that limits the result to 2 posts.
    $response = wp_remote_get( 'https://video.amniat98.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed' );

    // Exit if error.
    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the body.
    $posts = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );

    // Exit if nothing is returned.
    if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // If there are posts.
    if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) {

        // For each post.
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {

            // Use print_r($post); to get the details of the post and all available fields
            //print_r($post);
            // Show a linked title and post date.
            $allposts .= '<a href="' . esc_url( $post->link ) . '" target=\"_blank\">' . esc_html( $post->title->rendered ) . '</a>';
        }
        
        return $allposts;
    }

}
// Register as a shortcode to be used on the site.
add_shortcode( 'rest_posts', 'get_posts_via_rest' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `has_post_thumbnail`, `the_post_thumbnail` and `the_post_thumbnail_url`.

---

### Example

```
<?php
/**
* The Loop
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/
*/
if ( have_posts() ):
    while ( have_posts() ): the_post();

      /**
      * has_post_thumbnail()
      * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/
      */
      if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):
        the_post_thumbnail();

        /**
        * get_the_post_thumbnail_url()
        * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/
        */
        the_post_thumbnail_url();
      endif;
    endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

---

### Learn more

- https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/

Comment: This solution not working, I get posts from another Wordpress site whit json and I need code to show post images, title and link work perfect